# Несложный игровой сервер на python

Tags: python, django, разработка-игр

Решил попробовать написать несложную мобильную ММОРПГ, основные дейстия - перемещение по локациям, бои между перснажами и монстрами/другими персонажами, задания, сбор лута. Все действия расчитываются на сервере, и бои в том числе, которые могут проходить с участием большого количества игроков в одном бое.

Пишу на питоне, знаю django. Вопрос в том, какие инструменты использутся для создания сервера. Подойдёт что-то типа той же джанги или есть более специализированные/логичные инструменты?

Comment: А клиентская часть у вас на чём будет? Если не в браузере, а отдельное приложение, то джанга тут вряд ли вообще нужна. Нужен просто код, который будет обмениваться с клиентской частью данными.

Comment: @Xander django-rest вполне может взаимодействовать с чем угодно, в том числе с мобильными приложениями и даже програми под винду. Вопрос только в правильности выбора такой архитектуры.

Comment: @Xander отдельное приложение. Джангу думал взять потому что знаю её и там есть дефолтные штуки типа аутентификации и моделек.